# Is it possible to write any rational number using base pi

Tags: number-systems

Is it possible to write any rational number (say 1 or 2 or .15) using a number system that was base pi instead of a number system that used a rational number as its base?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But the number of digits required to represent a rational number will be infinite in general.

Comment: And what are the digits?  In base $\pi$ with digits $\{0,1,2,3\}$, then every number in $[0,1)$ may be written in the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k \pi^{-k}$.  Why not try to prove it yourself?

Comment: Yes but not on earth.

Comment: Would it be possible to write a whole number just using pi itself?  Like write 1 as pi or 2 as $\pi\pi$

Comment: @user2417339 That sounds like unary (such as tally marks) but with the symbol π

Comment: How many digits would your number system in base pi have?

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser So would that work using tally marks of pi (even though it would be completely pointless) or does it not even work?

Comment: @MARXOS Do you mean how many digits of pi?  It would be all of pi

Comment: @user2417339 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system should give you more information.

Comment: @GEdgar: you are right. Brain fart on my part.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : The issue : The general setup for a given base $b$ is to write a given Real number $a$ as $a_0 b^0 + a_1b^1+....+a_k b^k$  with $a_k$ an integer less than the floor of $b$.

EDIT 2: STILL needs some work, which I am doing right now. Will be back soon to rewrite, or, if necessary, delete. Comments are welcome.

In our case, for $\pi$ we want to represent ( I assume) a Real  number $a$ as $ \pi^0 a_0+ \pi^1 a_1+....+ \pi^n a_n ; a_j < \pi$

at each stage, you choose the largest number $a_k$ , so that $$a_0 \pi^0+a_1\pi^1+...+a_k \pi^k \leq a $$.

This is a monotone, non-decreasing sequence of Real numbers bounded above by $a$, so it will converge to its $lub=a $.

I think we need as a basis a Real number $x; |x|>1$.

Comment: You need to impose some more constraints on the coefficients $a_i$. Otherwise your process will terminate at stage $0$ with $a_0 = a$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Please note I used the constraint $a_j < \pi$ in the top line.

Comment: But there is no largest real number meeting the constraint $a_j < \pi$.

Comment: No, that is a general condition on the coefficients. I mean we find the sum as described above with $a_j < \pi$  and $ a_0 \pi^0+...+a_k \pi^k  \leq a $. I am not requiring the largest Real number less than $\pi$.

Comment: So what constraints are you imposing on the coefficients? Integers? Integers less than $\pi$? Or what? If you allow $a_k$ to be any rational or real number there won't be a largest $a_k$ satisfying your conditions.

Comment: Part of the problem is I am not clear on the requirements of the OP for a number to be a base. But I see your point. This clearly would not work with integer coefficients, but why not for Rational $a_j$?

Comment: With rational coefficients you still don't get a largest $a_j$ satisfying the conditions.

Comment: @RobArthan: Ok, let me think it through more carefully. I will edit to this effect.

Comment: See my first comment for the OP.  You will need to allow negative powers of $\pi$ also.

Answer (score 0):

We can write rational numbers in irrational bases; easily shown by $100$ base $\sqrt 2$ is 2. There are in fact problems and papers that I have seen that use base phi, $\frac{\sqrt 5 + 1}{2}$.

However, because pi is transcendental, it is not the solution of any polynomial with rational coefficients. This means that no rational number can be written as a sum of powers of pi, which is equivalent to the fact that you can not write any rational number base pi.

Edit: Of course, you can always write the numbers non negative integers less than or equal to the base in that base, like 2 base pi is still $2\cdot \pi^0 = 2$. I was talking about everything else.

Comment: $1_{\pi}$ is rational.

Comment: @Harry: what's $1_{\pi}$?

Comment: $1_{\pi}$ is $1$ in base $\pi$. It can be expressed as the ratio of two integers in base $\pi$ (namely $1$ and $1$), so it's rational.

Comment: @Harry: Your terminology is a bit confused: the number $1$ is independent of the base you represent it in. Something like $1_{10}$ means  the representation of $1$ in base $10$. So $1_{10}$ or $1_{\pi}$ aren't numbers but rather strings of symbols.  However you are quite right that the string of symbols "1" will represent $1 = 1 \times \pi^0$ base $\pi$ in any formulation of "base $\pi$" numbers that allows $1$ as a digit.

Comment: @RobArthan I suppose I was confused. Are you saying that, for example, $45_{\pi}$ is ($1$) the representation of $45$ in base $\pi$ ($1110.30022 \dots$) or ($2$) $4\pi+5$? Or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: @Harry: I was a little confused too. On reflection, there is a choice of terminology: $S_b$ can reasonably be either an operation on a string of base $b$ digits $S$ that returns an integer or an operation on an integer $S$ that returns a string of base $b$ digits. You were using the former interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer. But it's too big to be a comment.

There is a problem with non-integer bases. Let $B$ be an integer and let $b=B-1$. Then $$(0.bbbbbb\dots)_B = 1_B$$ 
just as we would expect.

In base $\pi$, however,  $\pi - 1 < 3$. So it shouldn't come as a surprise that 
$$(0.333333\dots)_B = \dfrac{3}{\pi-1} \approx 1.40083_{10} > 1_\pi$$

So ordering numbers base $\pi$ is more complicated than ordering numbers in an integer base. It also seems that some numbers can be expressed in more than one, non-trivial, way.

Comment: Yes, there is an entire Cantor set of numbers expressed in more than one way.